# How to cause a Test Run Error if AssemblyCleanup times out?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm using MSTest in Visual Studio 2010 and have the need to restore my database after all tests have run.

What I did was decorate a method with the [AssemblyCleanupAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblycleanupattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
<AssemblyCleanupAttribute()>
Shared Sub AssemblyCleanup()
    ' Restore my databases which takes a long time...
End Sub
```

Problem is the clean up takes a reasonable amount of time, so much so that the timeout is reached.

The only reason I started realizing that a timeout occurred is that in debug mode the Output window reports "...QTAgent32.exe, AgentObject: Cleanup: Timeout reached in cleaning up the agent.". Hence it fails very quietly and I would have loved if MSTest reported a Test Run Error.

What is the best way to detect and report the timeout? My ideal solution would be to report the timeout as a test run error.

Comment: I've to date found no way to detect the timeout. One thing that might help others is that if you run the cleanup code as a cleanup script instead (configure in the .testrunconfig and make your test project a console application and call AssemblyCleanup in the Main method) then at least the timeout won't cause databases to corrupt. Doing the aforementioned will spin up a different process, so it will run to completion whether the test run completes because of a timeout or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **you cannot cause MSTest to report an error if AssemblyCleanup times out**.

If you are encountering this issue, then at this point you need to consider if this limitation of MSTest is too great for you. There are other, and imho better, test frameworks out there.

If you decide to stick with MSTest and just want to ensure, at least, that the code/script in AssemblyCleanup runs to completion then you can choose to either run the clean up code as a Process. That way even if AssemblyCleanup internally calls a Thread.Abort then your Process runs to completion. It's messy though...

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the contents of each test in a transaction, and rollback the transaction at the end of the test?  See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381703(v=vs.80).aspx#dtbunttsttedp_topic7

Comment: The purpose of restoring of the database is not to revert changes. I restore the database such that after tests are run I'm left with a database with large amounts of data which means I can use it to continue manual testing thereafter with more realistic data.

Comment: So you're using the same database instance for your manual testing and automated testing?

Comment: That's correct. AssemblyCleanup could be doing anything else in the future, and I just want to ensure that when the timeout occurs I know about it.

Comment: @vansily: So why not use a separate database instance for your testing?  Then you don't have your manual data interfering with your test data.  Seems like automatically restoring databases over top of each other is a sure way to lose a lot of data quickly.

Comment: Changing the process unfortunately doesn't address the problem where MSTest would not report a test run failure if it times out when running AssemblyCleanup, may it be taking long to restore a database or releasing IO or unmanaged resources. But, as a last resort I'd have to :)